# Qiskit BasicAer & Aer

Tags: qiskit, programming, grovers-algorithm, simulation

While I'm simulating grover's algorithm, I found that with BasicAer backend it works well but with Aer it is not. What is the difference between `qiskit.providers.BasicAer` and `qiskit.providers.Aer` ?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the difference between BasicAer and Aer, take a look at this answer: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/4996/9858

And in term of BasicAer returns incorrect result, take a look here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/1838

Hope this helps.

Comment: Then you mean, BasicAer is the new version of Aer? Which one is better?

Comment: BasicAer is actually an older version of Aer. And so Aer should be better.

Comment: Hmm... I use serveral simulation method from Aer such as 'statevector, density_matrix, stabilizer, extended_stabilizer, matrix_product_state'. Grover's algorithm ran well with 'statevector' and 'density_matrix' but not with 'extended_stabilizer' and 'matrix_product_state'. So I use BasicAer, then the result came well. Why it happened?

Comment: The main difference is that BasicAer runs in Python and Aer runs in C++ and is therefore faster. In addition, Aer supports more features. Aer supports several simulation methods. The default method is 'statevector'. What did you see wrong when running with the 'extended_stablizer' and 'matrix_product_state' methods? Did you get error messages or results that you did not expect?

Comment: @YaelBen-Haim Nice!  Not to go off tangent but here is another question that I think you can answer very well: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14226/suppress-warnings.

Comment: When I implement the grover's algorithm with 'extended_stabilizer' and 'matrix_product_state' the result was wrong. I designed the Oracle part to come out |1111>. But, with extended_stabilizer it makes error https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14211/qiskit-simulation-of-grover-algorithm but, with matrix_product_state, it's output was |0011>. I wonder why it happened.

Comment: With 'matrix_product_state' it is surprising, since it is a stable code. Are you running the latest Qiskit version? It can be nice if you open an issue in github.com/qiskit-aer